# How do I block routes from a certain origin with cors and expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, cors, backend, request-headers

Right now I have enabled cors so it only allows one origin that can make a request to **ANY ROUTE**, but I want to make it so it also **blocks some routes for that one origin**. If their is any way, please answer this question! Thank you.

So far my code is

```js
app.use(cors({
  origin: process.env.HOST,
}));
```

Comment: What is the actual use case for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try something like this

```
const blacklisted = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (blacklisted.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    } else {
        callback(null, true)
    }
  },
}
```

Then you can use it like this,

```
app.get('/route', cors(corsOptions), (req, res, next) => {
  //...
})
```